How can I make a Button in base of PopupView[items, i, base] behave as a standalone button?
Consider the following code:
ClearAll[x];
x = 0;
Button["Click", (x += 1;)]
Dynamic[x]

Every time I click the button, the dynamic value of x is incremented by 1.
Now consider the following code:
ClearAll[x];
x = 0;
PopupView[
    {"Option 1", "Option 2"},
    1,
    Button["Click", (x += 1;)]
]
Dynamic[x]

The documentation of PopupView seems to suggest that base can be any expression. But when I use the same Button expression as before, I find that the value of x is not incremented with each click.
Is there a way to get the base Button to behave as the standalone one?

A PopupView will create a special "object" in the notebook that responds to mouse clicks. Your clicks are intercepted by this PopupView object before they get to the Button object. The third "base" argument allows you to provide an alternate display, but the PopupView is still the object "in control". What are you trying to do? What is it that you want to happen? If your clicks did get to the button, then how are you supposed to choose one of the PopupView options?

"Is there a way to get the base Button to behave as the standalone one?" What does that even mean? You've deliberately embedded the button inside of a PopupView, so it's not standalone. What behavior do you actually want, a PopupView or a Button?

@lericr I would like to update two symbols through the PopupView, an idx and a val, by doing something like this: PopupView[{"Option 1", "Option 2"}, Dynamic[idx], Button["Click", (val = "val related to this popup view")]].

Can you be more explicit in explaining how you want the update to work? Like, if Option 1 is selected, what should happen, and if Option 2 is selected, what should happen? I'm not grokking why the button needs to be there at all.

@lericr I would like to have multiple buttons in a row, with each button opening up a sub-list of choices. I would like to know: (a) which button was clicked, and (b) which index was selected from the chosen button. There are specific reasons (mostly having to do with uniformity of presentation) why I need to display a button rather than a PopupMenu.

If you are absolutely certain that my goal cannot be accomplished by displaying a button, I will try to use a different suggestion (if you have one). But it would mean having to tweak other parts of the UI as well.

Based on the comments (the question really should be revised to reflect the actual desired behavior), something like this might work:
values = {1, 1, 1};

Row[
  {PopupView[{"Option 1", "Option 2"}, Dynamic[val1, (val1 = #1; values[[1]] = val1) &], Button["First", None]],
   PopupView[{"Option 1", "Option 2"}, Dynamic[val2, (val2 = #1; values[[2]] = val2) &], Button["Second", None]],
   PopupView[{"Option 1", "Option 2"}, Dynamic[val3, (val3 = #1; values[[3]] = val3) &], Button["Third", None]]}]

(* You can dynamically display the updates with... *)
Dynamic[values]

I'm assuming here that your desire for a Button is purely a presentation issue, so I've made the buttons not actually able to do anything. You could come up with any visualization you want that looks like a button. I'm also assuming that there is a fixed number of these "buttons", but if it actually needs to be programmatically determined, then we'd need to add some complexity to this. Lastly, I didn't really spend much time thinking about this, but you might consider dispensing with the PopupViews altogether and doing the whole thing with "real" buttons. Or look into Toggler, TogglerBar, CheckboxBar, ListPicker, etc etc.
Or maybe you might want a TabView with "real" buttons on each tab. For example something like this:
TabView[
  {Button["first", values[[1]] = 1 + values[[1]]], 
   Button["second", values[[2]] = 1 + values[[2]]], 
   Button["third", values[[3]] = 1 + values[[3]]]}]


Heh! The whole thing is already in a TabView, so, nested views would be quite confusing. But I can use something similar to your first suggestion! Thanks!
